# I have just downloaded Android SDK r15 and I can't seem to download anything

Tags: android, api, sdk, download

I have just downloaded Android SDK r15 and I can't seem to download anything including API's, it says it's downloading but it doesn't move even after 3 hours ...

Comment: Please explain in a little more details... what are you trying to download? android tools or API's.... ?

Comment: I thinks a screenshot would be welcomed.